# XML string - select only certain nodes

Tags: xml, xmlreader, xpathnavigator

I tried looking this up on here but couldnt find a proper answer.  I have a XML string which has a bunch of nodes.
I want to extract only a couple of nodes from this string and append it with a new root element and return it.

I know how to do this by loading this onto an XMLDocument and selecting nodes.  Is there a better way of doing this using an XpathNavigator or XmlReader?

**This is my String**

```
<root>
  <node1/>
  <node2/>
  <node3/>
  <node4/>
  <node5>
</root>
```

I want my output string to be

```
<root>
   <node3/>
   <node4/>
 </root>
```

Has to be done in an efficient manner.

Comment: So you want to remove nodes 1, 3, and 5?

Comment: yes but in reality I might have to remove more nodes.  I guess what I mean to say is, there could be more than a total of 5 nodes out of which I need only 2.  Also my input is a string (i know i mentioned this in my post, just emphasizing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of simplicity, I would use `XDocument.Parse()`. And manipulate the DOM through the provided functions. Since the XML is provided as a string, probably small, I'm willing to bet that you will not see complexity problems.

If there are a lot of nodes to remove, I suggest you use a list of XPath strings. Then for each string, you can use `doc.XPathSelectElements()` to find all the elements and call `remove()` on each one. The resulting XDocument will have just the remaining nodes.

Comment: thanks for the answer. however even though I get the XDocument part, what method(s) would I use to achieve what I want?

Comment: this is what I tried, but it deletes everything except for the root            XDocument x = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring);

x.Root.Elements().Where(e => e.Name != "node3" || e.Name != "node4").Remove();

Comment: Can I ask more question here or do I have to open another forum.  (I want to add attributes to <node4/> based on <node3/>)

Comment: You should open another question to get detailed help. But the general idea is to select both elements then call `setAttributeValue()` on node3.